# CuPy not picking the CUDA_PATH

Tags: python, windows, conda, cupy

I have CUDA Toolkit installed using the Nvidia installer but for whatever reason CuPy points to the wrong path. I installed `cupy-cuda11x` using `pip` on a `conda` environment.

```
    (py39) E:\>python
Python 3.9.16 (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:30:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cupy
>>> print(cupy._environment._get_preload_logs())
CUDA_PATH: C:\Users\Arvind\anaconda3\envs\py39
Wheel shared libraries: C:\Users\Arvind\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\cupy\.data\lib
Adding DLL search path: C:\Users\Arvind\anaconda3\envs\py39
Adding DLL search path: C:\Users\Arvind\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\cupy\.data\lib
Preloading triggered for library: cutensor
CuPy wheel package built for CUDA 11.x
CuPy CUDA library directory: C:\Users\Arvind/.cupy/cuda_lib
Looking for cutensor version 1.6.2 (cutensor.dll)
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Arvind/.cupy/cuda_lib\11.x\cutensor\1.6.2\lib\cutensor.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Arvind/.cupy/cuda_lib\11.x\cutensor\1.6.2\lib64\cutensor.dll
Rejected candidate (not found): C:\Users\Arvind/.cupy/cuda_lib\11.x\cutensor\1.6.2\bin\cutensor.dll
File cutensor.dll could not be found
Trying to load cutensor.dll from default search path
Library cutensor could not be preloaded: Could not find module 'cutensor.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
Preloading triggered for library: nccl
Preload nccl not configured in wheel
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: Cutensor isn't part of the cuda toolkit and the cupy documentation clearly indicates yove to manually install it